# Why is websphere saying there is no configuration for MDB

Tags: java, ejb, websphere, message-driven-bean

I'm using ejb 2.1 MDB. I've created the bean and the ibm-bnd-xmi file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejbbnd:EJBJarBinding xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:ejb="ejb.xmi" xmlns:ejbbnd="ejbbnd.xmi" xmi:id="EJBJarBinding_1436860079989">
<ejbJar href="META-INF/ejb-jar.xml#ejb-jar_ID"/>
<ejbBindings xmi:type="ejbbnd:MessageDrivenBeanBinding" xmi:id="MessageDrivenBeanBinding_1436860521292">
<enterpriseBean xmi:type="ejb:MessageDriven" href="META-INF/ejb-jar.xml#TestMDB"/>
<resRefBindings xmi:id="ResourceRefBinding_1436860842233" jndiName="jms/qcf.QCF">
  <bindingResourceRef href="META-INF/ejb-jar.xml#ResourceRef_1436860842233"/>
</resRefBindings>
<resRefBindings xmi:id="ResourceRefBinding_1436861092345" jndiName="jms/ccqueue">
  <bindingResourceRef href="META-INF/ejb-jar.xml#ResourceRef_1436861092345"/>
</resRefBindings>
</ejbBindings>
</ejbbnd:EJBJarBinding>
```

When I deploy my MDB in websphere 8 i get the following exception

```
Caused by: com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.MDBException: MDB TestMDB has no MessageDrivenBeanBinding in ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xmi
at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.MDBListenerManagerImpl.create(MDBListenerManagerImpl.java:480)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.MDBHomeBean.activateEndpoint(MDBHomeBean.java:167)
... 74 more
```

I can see the configuration in the xmi file but it still spits out this error. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please show the MDB snippet from ejb-jar.xml as well.  It should have `<message-driven id="TestMDB">`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to see any `<mesage-driven>` entry in `ejb-bnd.xml`. Add an  entry like this for your *MDB*

**FOR EJB 3.1**

```
<message-driven
        name="StatusUpdateMDB">
    <jca-adapter activation-spec-binding-name="jms/MC_StatusUpdateActivationSpec" destination-binding-name="jms/MobileClaimStatusQueue"/></message-driven>
```

**For EJB 2.1**

```
    <message-driven id="Mdb21">
  <ejb-name>Foo/ejb-name>
  <ejb-class>ejbs.FooBean</ejb-class>
   <messaging-type>javax.jms.MessageListener</messaging-type>
   <transaction-type>Bean/transaction-type>
   <message-destination-type>javax.jms.Topic</message-destination-type>
    <activation-config>
     <activation-config-property>
       <activation-config-property-name>destinationType</activation-config-property-name>
       <activation-config-property-value>javax.jms.Topic</activation-config-property-value>
     </activation-config-property>
     <activation-config-property>
       <activation-config-property-name>subscriptionDurability</activation-config-property-name>
         <activation-config-property-value>Durable</activation-config-property-value>
      </activation-config-property>
      <activation-config-property>
         <activation-config-property-name>acknowledgeMode</activation-config-property-name>
         <activation-config-property-value>AutoAcknowledge</activation-config-property-value>
      </activation-config-property>
      <activation-config-property>
        <activation-config-property-name>messageSelector</activation-config-property-name>
        <activation-config-property-value>fooSelector</activation-config-property-value>
      </activation-config-property>
</activation-config>
</message-driven>
```

For EJB 2.1 reference , see the IBM doc [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSRTLW_7.5.5/com.ibm.jee5.doc/topics/rv6ejbprojects.html).

Comment: Is this allowed with ejb 2.1? I added this in the xmi file (not xml as xml is used only with ejb 3) and I got this:  org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.FeatureNotFoundException: Feature 'message-driven' not found. (file:///D:/IBM/RAD8/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/CWBE_66/bin/META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xmi, 13, 31)

Comment: @lemonTea edited the code for EJB2.1. you need to do the changes in ` ejb-jar-2.1.xsd`